# Unable to get OVRGrabber working to allow grabbing GameObjects for Oculus Quest development in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

I am trying to get basic grabbing with OVRGrabber working for an Oculus Quest game in Unity.

I can use the custom hands scene and everything works fine. However, when I try and implement the same in my own scene, I am unable to grab an OVRGrabble GameObject.

Here's the hierarchy for my OVRCameraRig. I am using the OVRControllerPrefab as child objects to LeftHandAnchor and RightHandAnchor:

[image]

For each of the OVRControllerPrefab GameObjects, I have a Rigidbody and Sphere Collider (set to isTrigger) along with the OVRGrabber script. For the OVRGrabber script, I have the sphere collider set to be the grab collider

[image]

Finally, for the grabble game object, I have a RigidBody, Box Collider (with is trigger not set) and OVR Grabble

[image]

For the life of me, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the GripTransform for your OVRGrabber is set to null. Usually your hand GameObject set should look like this. If you do not have a gripTrans gameObject, create a gameObject at the center of the hand and attach this to "GripTransform" for that hand's OVRGrabber.

[image: Hand]

[image: OVRGrabber]